# Error connecting with SAP ERP System with Pentaho ETL tool

Tags: database, etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, sap-erp

I am trying connect SAP ERP System with Pentaho Data Integration tools by required properties. As like below image. But didn't connect with SAP ERP System.
[image]

If I click on Test button then nothing saying. But, If I try to execute query then showing this error.
[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @HelpingHand.. If if click on Test button then noting saying. 
But, If I try to execute query then showing this error.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15130238/89793120-4a10d700-db47-11ea-87d1-12afa273a950.png

Comment: looks more like JDBC error. What is the *plugin specific acces method*? what is this plugin? novum connector for Pentaho? Refer to the [official Pentaho troubleshooting page](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Connecting+with+SAP+Systems) for integration

Comment: when you test the connection is it showing message of success ? @Badrul

Comment: @HelpingHand.. If I click on Test button then it nothing says.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the drivers again. Below links should provide you some additional info.

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/04/creating-a-connection-to-sap-hana-using-pentaho-pdi/

https://www.danielpradilla.info/blog/how-to-connect-pentaho-data-integration-to-sap-hana/

Comment: I need to connect SAP ERP system. And this SAP ERP not using Hana DB.

Answer (score 0):

The step in the background of your first screen shot, `SAP ERP Table Input` is not a standard Pentaho step, but a Plugin developed by IT-Novum. It is a product that has to be purchased (see [here](https://it-novum.com/blog/integrating-sap-data-with-pdi/)). But even that step doesn't allow direct queries using the table input step from Pentaho, it delivers its own input step. The reason is that SAP ERP doesn't allow direct database access at all, you have to retrieve data through RFC modules if you want to go through the SAP Netweaver server instead of accessing the database directly. This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZonHFcJ6Dgg) contains a demo around 7 minutes into the video, showing the plugin specific step.

You can use remote function modules like `RFC_READ_TABLE` to access tables and views with pentaho (and the `sapjco` library) alone, but it doesn't work through the regular Table Input step in Pentaho, you need to use the SAP Input step. And `RFC_READ_TABLE` has a number of limitations that make it pretty much useless for extended ETL tasks without a few modifications (see for instance this [SCN thread](https://answers.sap.com/questions/2089896/rfcreadtable-dump-while-reading-t006-urgent.html))

If you only need to access a very small number of tables with few fields and ideally only in a few transformations, the SAP input step can help you do that. But if this a cornerstone of a large ETL process, start looking into commercial tools to help you. Or, if this is a viable alternative for you, access the database directly. But there are possible license limitations (the Oracle db licensed by SAP only allows access for the SAPSR3 user) as well as technical reasons (for instance security risks) to avoid doing that.